# Is there a way to save all rosbag data into a .csv or text file?

Tags: ros, rosbag, rxbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I would like to extract the data from the rosbag and convert it into text or .csv file to use the data into Matlab and Excel. Is this possible ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55037/is-there-a-way-to-save-all-rosbag-data-into-a-.csv-or-text-file-?/) by [ETS-Dronolab](https://answers.ros.org/users/4112/ets-dronolab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2013-02-12

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mannish123123](https://answers.ros.org/users/94694/mannish123123/) on 2022-01-23**:
good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is taken from [this answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/29614/how-to-extract-data-from-bag/29618#29618) for a [similar question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/29614/how-to-extract-data-from-bag/):

> For simple message formats, you can convert directly to CSV from the command line:
>
> `rostopic echo -b file.bag -p /topic`
>
> This won't work well if your bag file contains arrays/images/pointclouds/etc... as it renders the entire message to text.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2013-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 20

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zkytony](https://answers.ros.org/users/26716/zkytony/) on 2017-02-10**:
This is so awsome

**Comment by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on 2018-06-04**:
What are the meaning of the -b and -p flags ?

### **Comment by [IanCol](https://answers.ros.org/users/26764/iancol/) on 2019-07-23**:\

Display messages in a bag file.

-p
Display messages in a matlab/octave-friendly plotting format.

From [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic#rostopic_echo).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's a quick way:

```
rosbag play mybag.bag
rostopic echo /foo > output.txt
```

This will output all message in the topic `/foo` to a yaml-formatted text file. You can then parse the file. It might be useful to output to multiple files for different fields. Let's say the message type on `/foo` is [Pose](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose.html):

```
rosbag play mybag.bag
rostopic echo /foo/position/x > output_x.txt
rostopic echo /foo/position/y > output_y.txt
rostopic echo /foo/position/z > output_z.txt
```

You can also look into [bagys](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosh/Overview/Bagys), which are an extension of the concept above.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2013-02-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-08-26**:
Hi there! Is the other way around possible. i.e., convert from a .txt to a .bag? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/9102/how-to-extract-data-from-bag/?answer=63877#post-id-63877) for a simple script to save all topics in the bag file as a seperate csv.

Please let me know if you found this useful or if you have any suggestions for how to improve it.

---

Originally posted by [NickSpeal](https://answers.ros.org/users/4117/nickspeal/) with karma: 81 on 2013-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A more flexible way of doing this could be with Pandas. After you record your data, you can sift through it to gather the information you need, add it to a dataframe, perform any operations on it, and save it to a .csv. For example, lets consider some points.

```
import rosbag
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point
import pandas as pd

# The bag file should be in the same directory as your terminal
bag = rosbag.Bag('./recorded-data.bag')
topic = '/your_topic'
column_names = ['x', 'y']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)

for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages(topics=topic):
    x = msg.x
    y = msg.y

    df = df.append(
        {'x': x,
         'y': y},
        ignore_index=True
    )

df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

---

Originally posted by [cwillia109](https://answers.ros.org/users/51647/cwillia109/) with karma: 49 on 2020-07-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [redsapph](https://answers.ros.org/users/56951/redsapph/) on 2020-07-23**:
This is a fantastic answer :). I think being able to convert rosbag into csv should not depend on rosbag play like the other answer. One thing though:
I found that import rosbag works inside your ros environment (there may be a specific py package outside ros, unsure) but geometry_msgs.msg should come with ros
The last thing you may need is 'pip install pycryptodomex' and 'pip install gnupg' if you get issues with these libraries when trying to 'import rosbag'